# LRT and $\text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$

Tags: uniform-distribution, likelihood-ratio, exact-test

We have one observation of variable $X$ that is distributed uniformly on $[0, \theta]$. Null hypothesis is $H_0 \colon \theta = 1$ and alternative hypothesis is $H_1 \colon \theta = 2$.

> What is the rejection region in terms of $\alpha$ (significance) for likelihood ratio test. When is this test exact?

I first calculated the likelihood ratio test like this
$$ \Lambda = \frac{f_{X \mid\theta = 1}(x)}{f_{X \mid \theta = 2}(x)} = \frac{\frac{1}{1-0}}{\frac{1}{2-0}} = 2.$$
Now, rejection region is defined as
$$P(\Lambda < c) = \alpha,$$ but this is the same as $P(2 < c) = \alpha$. Now I do not understand what to do now.

> What happens with likelihood ratio test if we switch hypothesis, so now $H_0\colon \theta = 2$ and $H_1\colon \theta = 1$. Is this test exact? If yes, find another test and compare powers.

I gather that now $\Lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ but anything else I do not know.

---

My question is therefore how do I continue in first part and what shall I do in second one.

Comment: Your calculation of the likelihood ratio is incorrect.  It should be $$\Lambda = \frac{I(0\le x\le 1}{2I(0\le x\le 1)} = 2I(0\le x\le 1).$$